# Wordpress plugin to generate .zip file dynamically

Tags: wordpress

I have a Wordpress website. In some pages the user can download several documents (.pdf files) and I would like to have a "Download all"  option. So the user is able to download all the documents on that page by once in a zip format.

Since the documents change frequently, I would like that the zip generation is dynamic (I mean by code/plugin) so I don't have to replace the zip manually every time a document changes.

I did some research for Wordpress plugins but the keywords for searching that I am using do not point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could search the keyword `wordpress plugin zip-attachments`